# Can I preview a PICHME.md file using GitPitch without commit and push?

Tags: gitpitch

When you're creating a presentation you regularly need to see a preview of your work. It's hard to commit/push for each review. Is there any other way for seeing the final output of GitPitch?

Comment: See [Developing Testing Locally](https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/wiki/Developing-Testing-Locally).

Comment: @wchiquito Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it as people might google this question before reading all the available documents ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to make changes and preview those changes without having to push every change to your remote git repo. The approach is detailed on the GitPitch Wiki, see the [Developing / Testing Locally](https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/wiki/Developing-Testing-Locally) page.

As that particular Wiki page states:

> Sometimes you may want to develop some or even most of the content for you presentation locally and then push the final PITCHME.md when you are done. While there is no dedicated tool for GitPitch that supports this kind of develop-then-preview workflow there is a simple approach that may be useful for some.

Comment: The link seems dead and redirects to the main page. While current documentation https://gitpitch.com/docs/ doesn't seem to contain such chapter.

Comment: GitPitch now offers GitPitch Desktop. A dedicated presentation tool for Linux, OSX, and Windows users. You can use it to develop, preview, and present directly on your desktop. Using GitPitch Desktop you can also work entirely offline to develop and present your slideshow presentations. The Desktop tool is a seamless desktop companion to the gitpitch.com markdown presentation service in the cloud. You can find more details on the GitPitch website https://gitpitch.com/desktop.

Comment: This is not available anymore for non paying users. GitPitch Desktop is only available to paying users, so this feature was removed and is only available in payed versions now.